# Не получается понять замыкание в JS

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Самые популярный пример с замыканием - это счетчик:

```js
var counter = (function() {
  var current = 0;
  return function() {
    current++;
    return current;
  }
})();

console.log(counter()); // 1
console.log(counter()); // 2
```

И понять не могу, почему, когда во второй раз вызывается функция counter значение переменной current не становиться 0?
Почему функция запоминает значение один, которое стало после первого вызова?

Answer (score 1):

Все просто.
В начале вызывается только внешняя функция.

var counter = (function() {
  var current = 0;
  return function() {...}
})();

То есть происходит присваивание counter вложенной функции и устанавливается значение переменной current = 0.

В итоге counter будет равен этой функции
function() {
    current++;
    return current;
  }

И затем при вызове counter вызывается только эта внутренняя функция.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что этот `return`

```
return function() {
  current++;
  return current;
}
```

возвращает не "голую" анонимную функцию, а функцию вместе с окружением, включающим экземпляры всех локальных переменных и параметров, видимых из этой анонимной функции и используемых в ней.

```js
function counterCreator() {
  var current = 0;
  return function() {
    current++;
    return current;
  }
}

var counter1 = counterCreator();
console.log("counter1", counter1(), counter1(), counter1());

var counter2 = counterCreator();
console.log("counter2", counter2(), counter2(), counter2());

console.log("counter1", counter1(), counter1(), counter1());
```